# How to iterate and sample from each category of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a script that calculates a sample size, and then extracts samples from each category in a dataframe evenly. I want to re-use this code for various dataframes with different categories, but I'm having trouble figuring out the `for` loop to do this:

```
df2 = df.loc[(df['Track Item']=='Y')]
categories = df2['Category'].unique()
categories_total = len(categories)
total_rows = len(df2.axes[0])
ss = (2.58**2)*(0.5)*(1-0.5)/.04**2
ss2 = ss / categories_total
ss3 = round(ss2)
one = df.loc[(df['Category']=='HOUSEHOLD FANS')].sample(ss3)
two = df.loc[(df['Category']=='HUMIDIFIERS')].sample(ss3)
three = df.loc[(df['Category']=='HOME WATER FILTERS')].sample(ss3)
four = df.loc[(df['Category']=='CAMPING & HIKING WATER FILTERS')].sample(ss3)
five = df.loc[(df['Category']=='THERMOMETERS')].sample(ss3)
six = df.loc[(df['Category']=='AIR PURIFIERS')].sample(ss3)
seven = df.loc[(df['Category']=='DETECTORS')].sample(ss3)
eight = df.loc[(df['Category']=='AIR CONDITIONERS')].sample(ss3)
nine = df.loc[(df['Category']=='AROMATHERAPY')].sample(ss3)
ten = df.loc[(df['Category']=='AIR HEATING')].sample(ss3)
eleven = df.loc[(df['Category']=='HOUSEHOLD FANS')].sample(ss3)
```

I need to loop through each category, taking a sample from each one evenly. Any idea how I can accomplish this task?

Comment: Hello! do you want to save each subsample ina csv file, or in a list? what is your final purpose? 

```
for category in categories: 
    df_sample = df.loc[(df["Category"] == category )].sample(ss3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `sample` instead:

```
df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.sample(ss3))
```